# Cron (hourly) task to execute a ruby script

Tags: ruby, cron, ubuntu-12.04

I have a ruby script that I have tested to be working that I would like to run as an hourly cron but cannot seem to get it firing properly.

The last thing I have tried was placing the line:

```
ruby ~/ruby_script.rb
```

in /etc/cron.hourly

Said ruby script is located in the home directory with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

as its top line.

I have looked into ruby & cron resources but they most seem to be for reoccurring tasks in a Ruby on Rails environment when I just want the script to run in my ubuntu environment. I have double checked that rails is installed as well.

I have had a lot of fun learning more about ubuntu over the past few months and will truly appreciate any assistance I receive here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check this tutorial on crontab out: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto 
Also see this previous Stack Overflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984134/cron-that-will-run-a-ruby-script-every-day-at-midnight
Hope it helps.

Comment: cron runs with a limited environment. PATH may not be set as you expect, so /usr/bin/env wont find it, even if the cron is able to find the script. Suggest changing `ruby` in cron.hourly to the absolute path of the `ruby` interpeter

Comment: Also check your system log to see any error messages that cron might be printing when running your command.

Comment: I have changed 'ruby' to 'path/to/ruby' based on the directory from 'which ruby' will update in a few hours.

Comment: Hmmm. Having the line path/to/ruby path/to/script isn't working. Any other ideas?

Comment: if you are using rvm please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219400/rvm-isnt-setting-environment-with-cron

Answer (score 0):

Try to use current user crontab

```
$ crontab -e
```

Add new cron job

```
0 * * * *  /bin/bash -l -c 'ruby ~/ruby_script.rb'
```

Using bash command to run helps to get `env` variables during script execution.

(for tests change 0 to * - script will try to run every minute)

To log errors you can try to add command:

```
0 * * * *  /bin/bash -l -c 'ruby ~/ruby_script.rb >> ~/ruby_script.log 2>&1 &'
```

Hope it helps.